# Random variable as source of variance for a second random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to obtain the pdf of a random variable with a Gaussian distribution $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, A)$, whose variance A is determined by another random variable A with an exponential distribution with $\lambda=1$.

So the process would be the following:

1. Obtain a particular value $a$ from random variable $A$
2. Obtain a particular value $x$ from random variable $X$ with variance $a$

I have found that the correct pdf for random variable X is:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\exp\left(-\sqrt{2}|x|\right)
$$

And I have also checked that this formula is correct doing a simulation. But, how can I compute this pdf analitically?

[Simulated histogram + plotted pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXScp.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. It looks like you've already found the analytical solution, which is $\exp\left(-\sqrt{2}|x|\right)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I have found the final solution and checked that indeed it is correct, but I would like to know how to derive this pdf by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $A$, $X$ has same distribution as $\sqrt A Z$ where $Z$ has standard normal distribution. So the coniditional density of $X$ is $\frac 1 {\sqrt A} \phi (\frac x {\sqrt A})$ where $\phi$ is the standard normal density. Finally the density of $X$ is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt a} \phi (\frac x {\sqrt a})e^{-a}da$. I will let you carry out this integration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kavi! Just one small additional question: why is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}}\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{A}}\right)$ instead of $\frac{1}{A}\Phi\left(\frac{x}{A}\right)$, since A is the variance?

Comment: The density of $tX$ is $\frac 1 t f_X(\frac x t)$. Note that $\frac 1 A \Phi(\frac x {\sqrt A})$ does not even inetgrate to $1$ so it is not a density funtion.